# Extracting text from a Python span tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm doing the selenium robot, I need to extract information from the page after the robot does a search, but I'm having trouble.

I have the HTML in the following image

[Image-here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLoFn.png)

I want to extract the texts from these italicized tags of "class = 'escapamentoLinhas'"

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

URL = '\x0\x0\x0\x0'

search = '\x0\x0'
print("Running...")

class ScrapingTJ:
    def __init__(self):

        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.get(URL)

        sleep(1)
        select = Select(self.browser.find_element_by_id('cbPesquisa'))
        select.select_by_value('NMPARTE')
        sleep(1)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="campo_NMPARTE"]').send_keys(CNPJ_CLARO)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('pbEnviar').click()
        sleep(2)

        dados = self.browser.find_element_by_id('listagemDeProcessos')
        HTML = dados.get_attribute("innerHTML")

        scraping = BeautifulSoup(HTML, "html.parser")
        # links
        links = scraping.find_all('a')
        for scrape in links:
            print(scrape.get_text())


        textos = scraping.find(class_ = 'espacamentoLinhas')
        subtextos = scraping.find_all('span')
        for ext in subtextos:
            print(ext.get_text())
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrapingTJ()
```

exit:

```
Exectdo:
Recebido em:




Exectda:
   Recebido em:
```

in `:` I should get '30/04/2007 - Vara das Execuções Fiscais Estaduais ' is underlined in the image

Comment: is there a method get_text() ? i think you should be using ext.text to retrieve the span texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the HTML image you provided, it looks like the element text is in the `div` element and not the `span`. You will need to extract text from `div` instead of `span`. I would replace this block:

```
textos = scraping.find(class_ = 'espacamentoLinhas')
subtextos = scraping.find_all('span')
for ext in subtextos:
    print(ext.get_text())
```

With this:

```
elements = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='espacamentoLinhas']")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

`span` only contains the text 'Recebido em:', and not the text you are looking for, which is `30/04/2007 - Vara das Execuções Fiscais Estaduais`. This text is actually contained in the `div` referenced in the XPath I included.

If you don't want to use `self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath`, you can probably just remove the `scraping.find_all('span')` part of your code:

```
 textos = scraping.find(class_ = 'espacamentoLinhas')
 for ext in textos:
     print(ext.get_text())
```

Comment: this last follow up didn't work he returned me

AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what data type `scaping.find()` return type is. I was expecting a WebElement, and I assumed it was same datatype as `subtextos` in your original example.